# How to have all users to download a different production apk version?

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

I am teaming up with a partner and they said I have to remove all ads from the app forever from all users that will download the app on a specific day.

The ads in my app is just a banner. I could remove them by eliminating the adview easily, but then if I wanted to put them back I would have to roll out a new apk version with ads enabled, which would show ads to all users, even those who downloaded the app in the promotion day.

is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, a simple solution would be a `SharedPrefference` value, that gets updated from a product purchase, that disables/hides the adview.

So, if the user connects once, you check if it has "the hide ads product", and on that day, you collect new downloads, and give them the product. It would be easier, instead of branching your apk, for ads/noads... [documentation for refference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html), and [how to make them free](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html)